Get data from PostgreSQL Database from table with : in name
I'm a beginner in Python. I'm trying to get data from a PostgreSQL database. Here is a query in Python
postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select * from ''abbott:Account" limit 100 ' 

I note that the table is called "abbott:Account", and I get the data with this particular request from DBeaver, everything is fine. But in Python I get a syntax error related to :. I could not solve the problem by any means. Tell me, how can I generate such a query in Python?
I try to use some characters in request, but i still have error

Your quotation marks are unbalanced.

I'm confused that this should work at all because I don't think it's valid SQL syntax? What is abbott? If that's a schema then use abbott.Account

Advice: fix your naming convention and don't use characters like that. Just a-z and _

Instead if describing the reported error, please post the actual error message including any associated context.

I think quotation marks are not correct, enclose table name with "".
Like this:
postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select * from "abbott:Account" limit 100;' 

Also it will be fine to share more info about used packages, version etc., so the issue will be reproducible.

No, I used the quotation marks correctly, just a typo in the question. This option works . Select * from the database.scheme."abbott:Account" limit of 100

@user23956254, if it's a typo in the question, then edit the post so that it accurately presents the actual code.
